# Easy creation/updating of Office Open XML Charts (PowerPoint preferred)

Tags: .net, ms-office, powerpoint, openxml

Does anybody know Office-independent .NET components supporting creation/updating full-fledged office open xml charts from different types of documents (PowerPoint preferred) in a couple of lines of code.

An example from MSDN *[How to: Insert a Chart into a Spreadsheet Document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc820055.aspx)*  does it in a difficult way (as far as I can understand I need to create all those child objects like axes *explicitly*), though many components reading/writing Excel 2007 charts allow creation of charts in a few lines of code, *implicity* creating child objects (axes, labels, tick marks, etc).

Aspose.Slides.Pptx doesn't seem to provide a deep-chart edition as well (like changing chart type, etc)

Though PowerPoint is preferred, solutions and ideas for other Office documents (like Word and Excel) which could be ported to PowerPoint are welcomed as well.

Answer (score 1):

Nixie, personally I'd stick with the OpenXML SDK v2
see http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=C6E744E5-36E9-45F5-8D8C-331DF206E0D0&displaylang=en

There is a bit of a learning curve, but once you get through that, I feel you'll have more control.
You'll also need some good xml skills.

**Tip:** Use the Document Reflector (part of the SDK). It is extremely useful.

Comment: I believe link in the message above refers to OpenXML SDK v2. When I asked 'easy' I meant 'easy than Open XML SDK v2'.

Comment: point taken! ;)
I've used Aspose's tools in the past, also, but always ended back at the OpenXML SDK and I found it was worth it once I got past the learning curve. Obviously it depends on your needs.